# Trigonometric Equation, quadratic using two functions

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics

I am struggling to know how to solve this equation as it involves more than one type of trigonometric function, I know how to do it with one repeated function. If a solution could be explained, that would be helpful as I can easily calculate the answer without understanding it.

Question:

$$4\sin^2{x} + 9\cos{x} - 6 = 0$$

for $0 < x < 720˚$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
Use $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$ to get:

$$4 - 4\cos^2 x + 9\cos x - 6 = 0$$

Use the substitution $u = \cos x$ and solve the quadratic equation.